# How to repair mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, data-recovery

I have a database server(Fedora 14) which mysql is running as the database server. Recently that server broke down and I was only able to get the database directory from the server.

I have tried to put that database directory which I was able to get from my broke down server into a mysql server which is running on another PC (also Fedora 14) but, only three tables had data and though the table names are shown, when I try to execute queries it says table not available except for three tables. I have more that 30 tables in that database.

Please tell me a way to recover those missing tables.

I have tried to repair tables as follow but it was not success,

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_ofm_mnu_jvs |
+-----------------------+
| Company               |
| CostCenters           |
| CostVariable          |
| Des_Note              |
| EDN_Main              |
| EDN_Sub               |
| Factory               |
| ICMT_Main             |
| ICMT_Sub              |
| IMT_Main              |
| IMT_Sub               |
| ItemLedger            |
| JC_InOutCrop          |
| JC_Main               |
| Ledger                |
| Log                   |
| OLD_Stock             |
| SRN_Main              |
| SRN_Sub               |
| St_BFG                |
| St_FGS                |
| St_OGS                |
| St_OLS1               |
| St_OLS2               |
| St_OLS3               |
| St_OLS4               |
| St_OLS5               |
| St_RAW                |
| St_RDS                |
| St_SPG                |
| SysUpdate             |
| Vw_AllStock           |
| Vw_AllStokMove        |
| Vw_AllStokMove1       |
| Vw_ExcropBalance      |
| Vw_JCSummary          |
| a_user                |
| act_months            |
| batchno               |
| certification         |
| e_email               |
| grn_main              |
| grn_sub               |
| item_code             |
| item_grade            |
| mtn                   |
| san                   |
| stocktype             |
| supplier              |
| uom                   |
| zc_Block              |
| zc_Cetification       |
| zc_FarmerAccount      |
| zc_FarmerCer          |
| zc_FarmerCompany      |
| zc_FarmerCrop         |
| zc_FarmerReg          |
| zc_IcsYear            |
| zc_Society            |
| zc_temfar_crop        |
| zc_temfar_main        |
| zc_user               |
+-----------------------+
62 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> repair table Company;
+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Op     | Msg_type | Msg_text                                  |
+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
| ofm_mnu_jvs.Company | repair | Error    | Table 'ofm_mnu_jvs.Company' doesn't exist |
| ofm_mnu_jvs.Company | repair | status   | Operation failed                          |
+---------------------+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think my tables are not MyISAM tables because when I run  myisamchk *.MYI I got follwing results,

```
myisamchk *.MYI
Checking MyISAM file: act_months.MYI
Data records:       2   Deleted blocks:       0
myisamchk: warning: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
- check file-size
- check record delete-chain
- check key delete-chain
- check index reference
- check data record references index: 1
- check record links
MyISAM-table 'act_months.MYI' is usable but should be fixed

---------

Checking MyISAM file: OLD_Stock.MYI
Data records:  115375   Deleted blocks:       0
myisamchk: warning: 7 clients are using or haven't closed the table properly
- check file-size
- check record delete-chain
- check key delete-chain
- check index reference
- check data record references index: 1
- check data record references index: 2
- check record links
MyISAM-table 'OLD_Stock.MYI' is usable but should be fixed

---------

Checking MyISAM file: zc_IcsYear.MYI
Data records:       0   Deleted blocks:       0
- check file-size
- check record delete-chain
- check key delete-chain
- check index reference
- check data record references index: 1
- check record links
[root@localhost ofm_mnu_jvs]# myisamchk *.frm
myisamchk: error: 'act_months.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'a_user.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'batchno.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'certification.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'Company.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'CostCenters.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'CostVariable.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'Des_Note.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'EDN_Main.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'EDN_Sub.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'e_email.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

myisamchk: error: 'Factory.frm' is not a MyISAM-table

---------

.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most make sure that you are running the same database version. Including the minor version. If the tables are MyISAM, than you can use `myisamchk` for recovery. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-table-maintenance.html

Comment: i was able to recover my data by putting the database table and ibdata1 file from the broke down pc in to a working mysql server.